# how to use single delete page for deleting data from mulltiple pages in php using sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

In this, I am trying to delete rows from multiple pages by redirecting then on a single page, but the problem is that when it redirects it deletes the data but also shows an error while it is not getting the another data. The if-condition is also not working.

What to do and how to do it?

```
<?php
 include('connect.php');
  if(empty($_REQUEST['b-id']))
 {
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$query="delete from contact where id='$id'";
$data=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if($data>=1)
    {
        echo "<script>
        alert('Data Deleted Suceefully');
        window.location.href='user-queries.php';
        </script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>
        alert('Process Failed');
        window.location.href='user-queries.php';
        </script>";
    }
}
 elseif(empty($_REQUEST['id']))
   {
   $bid=$_REQUEST['b-id'];
   $query1="delete from registration where id='$bid'";
   $data1=mysqli_query($con,$query1);
    if($data>=1)
    {
        echo "<script>
        alert('Data Deleted Suceefully');
        window.location.href='all-builders.php';
        </script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>
        alert('Process Failed');
        window.location.href='all-builders.php';
        </script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please show the full text of the error message.

Comment: i have dont it.. thanksss